# how to insert the array as bind element in snowflake stored procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The below code is throwing an error as `undefined bind element` `because array contains string which is enclosed in quotes eg: ["str1","str2","str3"]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_array(ARG ARRAY)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

let stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `INSERT INTO TABLE1( VARIANT_COLUMN) SELECT ?`},binds:ARG})
stmt.execute();
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in an array, but arrays are not supported as bind variables. You can use JSON.stringify to convert it to a string, which is supported as a bind variable. You can then use parse_json to convert it to an array in the SQL statement. This will force the caller of the SP to supply a valid variant since that's the type specified. However, if you want to force the caller to supply a valid array, you can change the input type to "array" and this is more tightly typed.

```
create or replace table table1 (variant_column variant);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_array(ARG ARRAY)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
let stringifiedArray = JSON.stringify(ARG);
let stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `INSERT INTO TABLE1( VARIANT_COLUMN) SELECT parse_json(?)`,binds:[ARG]});
stmt.execute();
$$;

call sp_array(array_construct('str1', 'str2', 'str3')); 
call sp_array(['str1','str2','str3']);

select * from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `TO_JSON` and `PARSE_JSON`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE1( VARIANT_COLUMN VARIANT);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_array(ARG TEXT)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

let stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText:`INSERT INTO TABLE1( VARIANT_COLUMN) SELECT PARSE_JSON(?)`
   ,binds:[ARG]})
stmt.execute();
$$;

CALL sp_array(TO_JSON([1,2,3]));

CALL sp_array(TO_JSON(['a', 'b']));


SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
-- [   1,   2,   3 ]
-- [   "a",   "b" ]
```